# Why is the CSS rule that I applied via the CSS injector module not active on my mobile device?

Tags: panels, theming

I have a panel row with two regions and I wish to re-order the 
display for mobiles. Below is what I wish to accomplish:

[image: Drupal Regions]

And I thought it would be as simple as the below css rule :

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{ 
   .pane-2 
    {
    display:block;
    }
}
```

But nothing happened with the above rules.

I am using the [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) module to apply the above css.

Can anybody help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Clear cache or CSS aggregation bug

[Comment #1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1588822#comment-6013780) in [issue # 1588822](https://www.drupal.org/node/1588822) contains some interesting hints that might help to answer your question:

- to see the changes, you must clear the cache. Since your question doesn't mention anything like that, make sure you did cear the cache.
- bugs in CSS aggregation can be problematic with specific CSS constructs. If you trigger one of those, it can result in CSS being omitted from the aggregation CSS file.

## CSS rule overwritten by another module

And the rules provided by this module might be overwritten by another module, as briefly mentioned in the last paragraph of the module's [readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/css_injector/tree/README.txt?h=7.x-1.x) ...

## CSS edits via external editor

[CSS edits via external text editor not displaying](https://www.drupal.org/node/2458957) (which only applies to the 7.x-2.x version, not to 7.x-1.x) might be what's causing the issue.